Xcode cloud how to use specific flutter version instead of latest?
Xcode cloud how to use specific flutter version like 3.19.6 instead of latest?

Replace these lines:
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --depth 1 -b stable $HOME/flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"

# Install Flutter artifacts for iOS (--ios), or macOS (--macos) platforms.
flutter precache --ios

# Install Flutter dependencies.
flutter pub get

with:
# Install Flutter using fvm.
brew tap leoafarias/fvm
brew install fvm
fvm install 3.19.6
fvm global 3.19.6

# Install Flutter artifacts for iOS (--ios), or macOS (--macos) platforms.
fvm flutter precache --ios

# Install Flutter dependencies.
fvm flutter pub get

Complete file ci_post_clone.sh file:
#!/bin/sh

# The default execution directory of this script is the ci_scripts directory.
cd $CI_PRIMARY_REPOSITORY_PATH # change working directory to the root of your cloned repo.

# Install Flutter using fvm.
brew tap leoafarias/fvm
brew install fvm
fvm install 3.19.6
fvm global 3.19.6

# Install Flutter artifacts for iOS (--ios), or macOS (--macos) platforms.
fvm flutter precache --ios

# Install Flutter dependencies.
fvm flutter pub get

# Install CocoaPods using Homebrew.
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 # disable homebrew's automatic updates.
brew install cocoapods

export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
gem install cocoapods
# Install CocoaPods dependencies.
cd ios && rm -rf Pods && gem install cocoapods && pod install
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install

exit 0


replace this line
# Install Flutter using git.
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --depth 1 -b stable $HOME/flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"

with this
# Install Flutter using git.
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --depth 1 -b VERSION_NO $HOME/flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"

SO IF THE VERSION you want to use is 3.10.5
it will become
# Install Flutter using git.
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --depth 1 -b 3.10.5 $HOME/flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"
full code becomes this
#!/bin/sh

# Fail this script if any subcommand fails.
set -e

# The default execution directory of this script is the ci_scripts directory.
cd $CI_PRIMARY_REPOSITORY_PATH # change working directory to the root of your cloned repo.

# Install Flutter using git.
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --depth 1 -b stable $HOME/flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"

# Install Flutter artifacts for iOS (--ios), or macOS (--macos) platforms.
flutter precache --ios

# Install Flutter dependencies.
flutter pub get

# Install CocoaPods using Homebrew.
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 # disable homebrew's automatic updates.
brew install cocoapods

# Install CocoaPods dependencies.
cd ios && pod install # run `pod install` in the `ios` directory.

exit 0

